# Can't understand what does the Trailing commas do here?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I am stuck when looks at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069840/16673688) whch talks about how to sorting object property by values

```js
const maxSpeed = {
    car: 300, 
    bike: 60, 
    motorbike: 200, 
    airplane: 1000,
    helicopter: 400, 
    rocket: 8 * 60 * 60
};
console.log( Object.entries(maxSpeed))
const sortable = Object.fromEntries(

    Object.entries(maxSpeed).sort(([,a],[,b]) => {
    console.log(a,b)
    return a-b
    })
);

console.log(sortable);
```

Why using a Trailing commas there, why it makes it returns `[1]` item in the nested array (e.g. [car,300 ][0])?

By looking at mdn descrption about the trailing comma, I still don't have any ideas:

> Trailing commas (sometimes called "final commas") can be useful when adding new elements, parameters, or properties to JavaScript code. If you want to add a new property, you can add a new line without modifying the previously last line if that line already uses a trailing comma. This makes version-control diffs cleaner and editing code might be less troublesome.

Any hints and comments will be appreciated.

Comment: FYI "trailing" means _after_ but the commas in the code here are "preceding", ie _before_. Getting the terms right will help with searches in future

Comment: `console.log([,,0,,0]);` now with destructuring `[, a]` it is saying I do not care about index 0, but I want index 1 to be stored in variable `a`

Comment: @Phil, thank you!! Just curious how do we call the comma in the js code here? When I search online, search comma in js, the top result is just trailing operator and comma operator

Comment: @epascarello, thanks, this make more sense and clear!

Comment: Yeah, this would be a tricky one to search for so I don't blame you for not finding answers. The technical term for this would be _"omitting indexes"_ or _"specific index"_ in _"javascript array destructuring"_

Comment: @Phil, thanks so much;) That makes more sense